# Why Does The Layout Engine Kick In, In This Example?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I created a Playground project with only two Views: one label in the center of the screen, and one button sticking at the lower part of the screen. When I launch that example, everything works perfectly fine.

But as soon as I add a Layout Constraint to the Label view, then the Button view jumps to the top of the screen!

Nota Bene: I use `translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on both views.

Here is the code without the constraints:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let liveview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 600))

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 123.5, y: 566, width: 50, height: 50))
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.setTitle("BUTTON", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
button.sizeToFit()
liveview.addSubview(button)

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 134.75, y: 289.75, width: 50, height: 50))
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.textColor = UIColor.blue
label.text = "LABEL"
label.sizeToFit()
liveview.addSubview(label)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = liveview
```

And here is the result. Which is expected, there are no constraints yet. Please notice the position of the Button view: it is at the bottom of the screen.

[image: First Screenshot - no constraints applied]

Now I am adding a constraints to the **Label View**. The consequence of this adding is that the Button View jumps at the top of the screen! Here is the corresponding code, and the result is following:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let liveview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 600))

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 123.5, y: 566, width: 50, height: 50))
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.setTitle("BUTTON", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
button.sizeToFit()
liveview.addSubview(button)

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 134.75, y: 289.75, width: 50, height: 50))
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.textColor = UIColor.blue
label.text = "LABEL"
label.sizeToFit()
liveview.addSubview(label)

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: liveview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

print(liveview.constraints)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = liveview
```

[image: Second Screenshot - the label constraint is applied]

If you are interested, there is the result of printing the constraints list here, which confirms that the Button View has no associated constraints:

```
[<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000008d890 UILabel:0x7fc2c3f06c20'LABEL'.centerX == UIView:0x7fc2c3d030c0.centerX   (active)>]
```

My question is the following: why does the Layout Engine moves a View whereas with no associated constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` tells *Auto Layout* to not convert your view's `frame` to constraints, so your `UIButton` has no constraints.  Your `UIButton` is under constrained and *Auto Layout* can put it wherever it thinks is best.  Usually this means at horizontal and vertical offsets of `0`.

In your first example, both the `UIButton` and `UILabel` are unconstrained, and since there are no constraints at all, the layout engine doesn't run.

In your second example, as soon as you add a constraint to `UILabel`, the layout engine kicks in and starts placing things.  Note that it centers your label as you asked, but it also moves it to the top of the screen because the vertical position is unspecified.  It then moves your button to horizontal offset `0` and vertical offset `0`.  Again, since your button has no constraints, *Auto Layout* is free to move it wherever.

If you like your button where you put it with the frame, then simply do not set `translateAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints = false`.  Leave it set to `true`.

For your label, once you start down the path of giving it constraints, you should make sure it is fully specified.  Give your label a vertical constraint, and constraints for width and height if you desire to set them to something different than their intrinsic values.

Also, note that when you activate constraints by setting `isActive = true`, the constraint gets added to the *appropriate* view.  If you were to add *height* and *width* constraints to your button, those constraints would be added to `button.constraints` and not to `liveview.contraints`.  If you were to create a constraint that makes the button's width equal to the label's width, then this constraint would be added to their common ancestor's constraints.